# Background does not take the whole page Angular CSS

Tags: css, angular, background

A simple question that might help me to ask a more complicated problem that I will not explain here now.

Do you know why the red color does not take all the background of the page?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hp237w?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html

Of course in my problem I do not want to modify the files 'index.html' and 'style.css'

Thank you in advance, have a nice day

Comment: just to be clear, you want div to fill the page without using css? or just want to know why it does not fill?

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I just want to know why the background does not take all the page

Comment: because you didn't apply it to the whole page

Comment: I downvoted, because this question shows no research effort what so ever. This is something you could have learned easily through a simple Google search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `background-color: red` only applies to your div, which has a height of whatever total height of the elements within it by default. In order to take place of the entire page you just need to set the height to 100vh

```css
.back {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Can you give some more details? I tried in the stackblitz link you provided and it works there

Comment: There is a gap between the url and the text. But I think it's just about stackblitz. Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 1):

The parent block element, in this case `<body>`, does not have a 100% height. It also has by default a certain margin. The body element's block parent also has no height set. This is the `<html>` tag. You can fix this in two ways if you don't want to edit a global css file:

Add this in your component css, which is pretty ugly and so much frowned upon

```
::ng-deep body,
::ng-deep html {
  height:100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.back {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Another way is to make the position absolute. This work because the relative parent of the element is the <strike>`<html>` element</strike> viewport:

```
.back {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: `This work because the relative parent of the element is the <html>` --> it's not the html but the viewport

Comment: this explanation is wrong, even you set body to full height, the div still does not fill.

Comment: @ABOS, I said more than just putting the body to height: 100%

Comment: @PierreDuc, in OP's case, the body height does not matter.